# Custom model binding not being executed

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, model

I have two custom binders to get `DateTime` and `DateTime?` to bind.

I'm registering them in the `Global.asax` like:

```
public class MvcApplication : HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);

        ModelBinders.Binders[typeof (DateTime)] = new DateTimeModelBinder();
        //ModelBinders.Binders[typeof (DateTime?)] = new NullableDateTimeModelBinder();

        //ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof (DateTime), new DateTimeModelBinder());
        //ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime?), new NullableDateTimeModelBinder());
    }
}
```

I've also tried it like this:

```
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof (DateTime), new DateTimeModelBinder());
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(DateTime?), new NullableDateTimeModelBinder());
```

However, they are never being hit.

The model binding classes are here (stolen from the Internet):

```
public class DateTimeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        DateTime dateTime;

        var isDate = DateTime.TryParse(value.AttemptedValue,
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture,
            DateTimeStyles.None,
            out dateTime);

        if (!isDate)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName,
                $"Cannot bind value {value.AttemptedValue} to a DateTime");
            return DateTime.UtcNow;
        }

        return dateTime;
    }
}
```

and here:

```
public class NullableDateTimeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(value.AttemptedValue))
        {
            return null;
        }

        DateTime dateTime;

        var isDate = DateTime.TryParse(value.AttemptedValue, Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime);

        if (!isDate)
        {
            bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, $"Cannot convert {value.AttemptedValue} to a DateTime.");
            return DateTime.UtcNow;
        }

        return dateTime;
    }
}
```

What as I missing?

Comment: Can you share your model binder class? Did you inherit them from DefaultModelBinder?

Comment: Maybe this is can help you http://blog.greatrexpectations.com/2013/01/10/custom-date-formats-and-the-mvc-model-binder/

Comment: @umutözkan That's the post I was following.  Still not hitting the binders though.